# svn error when commit directory

Tags: svn

I use svn to commit a folder a checked out before and I get the message "containing working copy admin area is missing"

This is the command I used:

```
svn commit -m svn: /home/user/workspace/data/xyz
```

The path `/home/user/workspace/data/xyz`  is on my local pc where `xyz` is the folder I checked out before.

Comment: If you run `cd /home/user/workspace/data/xyz ; svn status`, what is the output?

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your .svn folder has been deleted in this directory. Try executing "svn update". If that doesn't work, delete everything in this folder and then try "svn update" again.

Comment: 'Delete everything in that folder' - you realize, of course that OP may lose all the work done in that directory? And, of course, if the directory is missing .svn folder simple update won't help - you'll have to move `xyz` out of the way first, and then do the recursive update of its parent.

Comment: Correct, data will be lost if you delete everything under that folder. Can either ... must back up work in the folder first, or check out the project in another directory (same revision) and copy the .svn folder into the failing folder.